# groupCount using lambda step fails in OLAP with SparkGraphComputer

Tags: apache-spark, titan, gremlin

I want to compute groupCount on a transformation of a specific property value available on a type of node in a graph. Seems to work fine with `graph.traversal()`, but doesn't work with `SparkGraphComputer`.

Excerpt from the general traversal:

```
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('webSession').values('channelSessionId')
            .map { it.toString().substring(0, 5)}
            .groupCount().order(local).by(values, decr)
==>[013b7:15,03190:11,04132:10,08c6a:10,028aa:9,005fe:9,09217:9,
    03ee8:9,0618d:9,0a0d3:9,079d5:9,055c5:9,05b15:9,
    0068b:8,005c0:8,03d30:8,009f8:8,07561:8,00d90:8,
    07794:8,066b9:8,09e13:8,09e9c:8,057b7:8,04781:8,...]
```

Excerpt from SparkGraphComputer:

```
gremlin> g = graph.traversal().withComputer(SparkGraphComputer)
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('webSession').values('channelSessionId')
            .map { it.toString().substring(0, 5)}
            .groupCount().order(local).by(values, decr)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

How do I convert this query to an OLAP query?

Another related question: if I am only interested in the first 5 elements in the groupCount `Map<>` object, is there any way to get that?